# DocuSign API: updateDocuments with Anchor Tagging

Tags: docusignapi

I need to create an envelope that contains a PDF with "sign here" tabs (the PDF contains anchor tags).

However, it is time consuming to generate, so I'm attempting to [create](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/Envelopes/create) an envelope with a placeholder PDF (a fixture, with no anchor tags). I send the fixture PDF along with recipients and their [tabs](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeRecipientTabs/list/#/definitions/signHere) in the initial request.

However, when I update the envelope's documents, using [EnvelopeDocuments: updateList](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeDocuments/updateList), to PUT the real PDF (which includes anchor tags), the recipient "sign here" tabs are not present.

If I use the `create` the envelope using the same document, the recipient "sign here" tabs are present.

Is there a way to update the documents for an envelope and have the recipient "sign here" tabs appear for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue by doing the following:

1) [Create envelope](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/Envelopes/create) with: `draft` status, a fixture PDF with no anchor tags, and recipients with tab data.

2) [Update documents](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeDocuments/updateList/) (with the real PDF to sign).

3) [Update envelope](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/Envelopes/update/) by `PUT`ing the original recipients in 1 (note: `advanced_update=true` needs to be present in the query string in order to update the `recipients` object.